# PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF is not working why?

Tags: sqlite

I am running SQLite3 version sqlite-3.6.12 and I have successfully
ported it to my OS.  The problem I am seeing is that when I execute the
command  "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF" it returns "OFF" but I am still seeing
*.db-journal files being created. It is critical that these files are not
created for the purpose of my project.  When I step through the code
sqlite3PagerJournalMode is returning PAGER_JOURNALMODE_OFF so I am wondering
if setting journal_mode=OFF should still produce these files or if there is
something else that I am missing.Please help

I also tried PRAGMA main.journal_mode = OFF and PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY.But the journel file is creating as such !!!!

Answer (score -1):

Compile your application with the ption macro:

**SQLITE_ENABLE_ATOMIC_WRITE**

If this C-preprocessor macro is defined and if the xDeviceCharacteristics method of sqlite3_io_methods object for a database file reports (via one of the SQLITE_IOCAP_ATOMIC bits) that the filesystem supports atomic writes and if a transaction involves a change to only a single page of the database file, then the transaction commits with just a single write request of a single page of the database and no rollback journal is created or written.